# How do i get this array to end?

Tags: java

Hey, so i have this hw assignment and i have to write a program that allows the user to input students names and grades and give back the higest lowest and average. The only problem is there is a max 50 students in the class(or so the sheet says) and there are only 10 students names and grades on it. How do i get the array to end after the last student?

```
static final int MAX = 50;
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int index, average;
    int highest = 0, student = 1;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String [] students = new String[MAX];
    int[] grades = new int[MAX];

    System.out.println("Please enter the name of the student and their test grade");
    System.out.print("Students: ");
    for(index=0; index<MAX; index++)
        {
            students[index] = keyboard.nextLine();
            student = student + index;
            if(students[index]=="Done"))
            {
                student = student - 1;
                continue;
            }

        }
    System.out.print("Grades: ");
    for(index=0; index<student; index++)
        grades[index] = keyboard.nextInt();
    averageMan(grades, student);
    for(index=0; index<student; index++)
        if(grades[index] < averageMan(grades, student))
            System.out.println(students[index] + " Your test grade was " +
                            "below the class average. Step it up.");
    for(index=0; index<student; index++)
        if(grades[index] > highest)
            highest = grades[index];
    System.out.println("The highest test grade in the class goes to " +
                    students[highest] + " with a grade of " + grades[highest]);
}

public static int averageMan(int[] g, int s)
{
    int index, sum = 0;
    int averages;
    for(index=0; index<s; index++)
        sum = sum + g[index];
    averages = sum / s;
    return averages;
}
```

}

Comment: Your program is small already, but try to condense it into the smallest necessary part when asking for help (for example, you could have ommited the `averageMain` method). Also you aren't actually trying to make the *array* (just a storage structure) end, you are trying to make your *loop* exit early.

Answer (score 3):

Use Collections, not arrays. Their api is a lot more usable.

Read the [Collections Trail](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html) to get started.

If you want a drop-in replacement for an array, [use a List](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html), if you want uniqueness, [use a Set](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could loop round collecting student details until the user enters a specific token that indicates that they have finished entering details.

**EDIT** Which looks like what you're trying to do..... but `continue` goes to the next item in the loop. You want to `break` out don't you?

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the `students` array with empty strings. Also Initialize the `grades` array with `-1`. In your loop for calculating average/highest/lowest, check for empty string and -1.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
student = student + index;
if(students[index]=="Done"))
{
  student = student - 1;
  continue;
}
```

to:

```
if(students[index]=="Done"))
{
  break;
}
student = student + 1;
```

Then you will quit the entry loop when a student's name is input as "Done" and the variable `student` will contain the number of students that were input.

Answer (score 0):

1) Hey, why are you doing this?

```
        if(students[index]=="Done"))
        {
            student = student - 1;
            continue;
        }
```

2) you can divide code into smaller methods

3) you can use Collections API as someone suggested.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment ?

Comment: Well it's pointing in the right direction anyway. I think if this continue is changed to break then it will work.

Comment: What you probably want is `break`, so you exit the for loop. `continue` just skips the loop content that comes after it for the current iteration.

Comment: @krookedking: thanks, my answer was expanded. I'm not going to publish the whole answer as it is HW,

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to use a collection class, like java.util.ArrayList instead of an array. If you have to use arrays, maybe you could reallocate the array each time you add a new Student? This page has an example of how to do that - [How to resize an array in Java](http://www.source-code.biz/snippets/java/3.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop has three parts, the middle part resolves to a true/false condition.  It can be simple, like you have or complex, like this:

```
for(index=0; index<MAX && !done; index++)
```

Where `done` is a `boolean` that is false until you detect a value that indicates you want to stop then becomes true.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a generic array list http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/generics-136597.html